# Oracle SQL date getting first day of last quarter and last day of last quarter

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, to-date

I've been asked to provide an Oracle PL/SQL solution if a file is loaded into the system
for example between the dates of 1st Jan 2017 - 31st March 2017 I should
created two dates from the last quarter a loaded **from date** of 
1st Oct 2016 and loaded **to date** of 31st Dec 2016. This should be future prove meaning it should work for future years, so if a file is loaded into the system lets say 21st August 2019, it should have a **from date** of 1st April 2019 and a **to date** of 30th June 2019.

[image]

This should be a PL/SQL solution most probably a procedure returning two dates to the main program and the **to and from date** returned should be in the format of DD/MM/YYYY.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what you have tried so far can you share that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this solution?

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q'), -3), 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS output_from_date,
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'Q')-1, 'DD/MM/YYYY') AS output_to_date
FROM dual;

OUTPUT_FROM_DATE    OUTPUT_TO_DATE
01/04/2017          30/06/2017
```

Comment: It worked! Provides the start and end dates of the last completed quarter.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is

```
select
dateadd(day, 1, (last_day(dateadd(quarter, -2, current_timestamp()), quarter))) as last_qtr_start,
last_day(dateadd(quarter, -1, current_timestamp()), quarter) as last_qtr_end
from dual;
```